# How to get all function names in VBScript and NOT execute script codes by using msscriptcontrol?

Tags: vbscript

How to ONLY get all functions & procedures name, instead of writing parser by myself?

Take the following vbs codes as example, which include 1 functions, 1 procedures, 2 statements, I want to get the function and procedure name:  1)"**GetValue**" 2) "**ABC_Result**"

Although `IScriptControl::AddCode` provided by Microsoft can work, whose problem is that
it ALWAYS execute the statements(such as "ABC_Result 20", "While True Wend") default?

//\test.vbs

```
Function GetValue(varVal)
  GetValue = varval*2
End Function

Sub ABC_Result(count)
  'msgbox is not allowed in server side, so use beep

  Dim WshShell
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  beep = chr(007)
  Dim i
  For i=0 To CInt(count)
    WshShell.Run "cmd /c @echo " & beep, 0
  Next
End Sub

ABC_Result 20

While True
Wend
```

Comment: 1) Grammar and structure make this difficult to readily follow; and 2) if I understand your question, are you looking to either capture the Function/Sub *names*, or looking to capture their text? Can you please update your question so it's a bit easier to understand? :)

Comment: Thanks for Lizz's comments.   I simplify my question, hope you can understand it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a "parser" may one way, using string functions like Instr() or even regular expressions.

However, there are third party tools like http://www.sourceformat.com/vbscript-formatter.htm which may give you cross-reference lists.